# Installing file_key_management

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Platform:10.1.31 MariaDB xampp
I am using the following query :
INSTALL PLUGIN file_key_management SONAME 'file_key_management.dll';

to install file_key_management, lm getting :
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "INSTALL" at position 0)
SQL query:

INSTALL PLUGIN file_key_management SONAME 'file_key_management.dll'

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1126 - Can't open shared library 'C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\file_key_management.dll' (errno: 2, )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download MariaDB from this link http://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/mariadb-10.1.31/win32-packages/mariadb-10.1.31-win32.zip then extract the archive and put the specified DLL into the `C:\xampp\mysql\lib\plugin\` folder

Comment: Thank you, Im trying it out now

Comment: now l am getting: mysqld.exe: Cannot decrypt C:/xampp/mysql/keys/key.enc. Wrong key?

Comment: Take a look at this excellent guide http://www.chriscalender.com/an-introduction-to-mariadbs-data-at-rest-encryption-dare-part-1/

Comment: Thank you, l got it to work your answer helped but l had to do a few more tricks. Once more question: where is the encrypted version of the tables viewed? from the front end, on phpadmin the tables data is not encrypted. Where am l supposed to see the encrypted data fro

Comment: If you disable the `file_key_management` plugin - you will be able to see the encrypted data.

Comment: Thank you, How do l do Mysql aes_encrypt on a column using the ENCRYPT KEY, how would l include it in this query: This doesn't work though, it just shows what l am trying to achieve :    INSERT INTO accounts (id,email,name)
VALUES (1,
AES_ENCRYPT("Athene",ENCRYPTION_KEY=1),AES_ENCRYPT("mutyambiziathene@gmail.com",ENCRYPTION_KEY=1));

Comment: You should provide the `key` as a second argument `INSERT INTO accounts (id,email,name) VALUES (1, AES_ENCRYPT("Athene","my_secret_key"),AES_ENCRYPT("mutyambiziathene@gmail.com","another_secret_key"))`

Comment: What would be the use of using file_key_management, if a constant for the file_key_management API can not be used

Comment: It is used when you need transparent encryption of entire table or even entire database and you want to keep the secret key(s) outside of your source code and outside your database itself. To protect if someone gets access to the database files - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-at-rest-encryption/

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, one last thing , is there any plugin you can recommend for encrypting the table contents themselves

Comment: I do not quite understand your question. You can either encrypt the data by yourself using the above mentioned `AES_ENCRYPT`, encrypt it in your middleware before storing in the database, or use the provided `data ecnryption in rest` with `file_key_management`